# How to control relay using serial communication, Silicon Labs CP2102N

Tags: python-3.x, uart, serial-communication

I tried below python script to control the relay module via serial communication. I cannot see any toggle in relay. Can someone tell what the issue here.

Device Specification: Model: SH-UR01A
Main Chip: Silicon Labs CP2102N
Interface: Serial Interface
Pin Definition: COM,NO,NC
Connectors:
USB Type A, 3-PIN Terminal Block
USB 2.0; Compatible USB 1.1
Plug and Play after one-time driver installation;

```
import serial
import time

# Configure the serial port
serial_port = serial.Serial('COM3', baudrate=9600)  # Replace 'COM3' with your specific port and 9600 with the appropriate baud rate

# Function to control the relay
def control_relay(channel, state):
    command = f"AT+CH{channel}={state};\r\n"  # Format the command with the desired channel and state
    serial_port.write(command.encode())  # Send the command
    print(command)
    time.sleep(0.1)  # Delay to allow relay to respond

control_relay(1, 1)  # Close the relay of channel 1
print("Sending command:ON")
time.sleep(60)  # Wait for 2 seconds
#control_relay(1, 0)  # Switch on the relay of channel 1

# Close the serial port
serial_port.close()
```

Tried above code, didnt work as aspected.

Comment: HI! Can you give us some more information on your issue ? What have you tried ? DO you have a datasheet/specifications for your device ?

Comment: I have tried sending command over Putty, device works fine. No problem with device. When i tried sending the same over python script i couldnt turn ON,OFF relay.

Comment: ok. I don't have a manual or datasheet for this product, but based on [some amazon review](https://www.amazon.de/-/en/SH-UR01A-Relay-Controller-Computer-Laptop/product-reviews/B09PYML6Q7/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_show_all_btm?ie=UTF8&reviewerType=all_reviews) have you tried not adding the semicolon, CR (`\r`) and LF (`\n`) ?

Comment: See line #7 in code, i have added it.

Comment: exactly. the reviews say don't add it. maybe try : `command = f"AT+CH{channel}={state}"`

Comment: Didnt workout with this change.

Comment: ah. you probably also need to specify the correct encoding for your command. Probably it's as ASCII -- so maybe try  `serial_port.write(command.encode('ascii'))`.

Comment: Tried this but didnt work. However i tried to read from the serial port, it printed E instead of AT+CH1=1

Comment: without a user manual or datasheet there's really not much else I can suggest, sorry. Maybe you should try and contact the manufacturer ?

Answer (score 0):

Recently bought a DSD Tech SH-UR01A and had similar difficulties getting the thing to work. The script below works fine and should give you the answers you're looking for (even though it's not python). Paste it in a file, open it in your browser and it should give you this output:

[image]

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    if ("serial" in navigator) {
      my_serial = {
        port: null,
        writer: null,
        is_open: false,
      }
      document.getElementById('select-port').addEventListener('click', async () => {
        // Prompt user to select any serial port.
        try {
          my_serial.port = await navigator.serial.requestPort();
          document.getElementById('action-port').removeAttribute('disabled')
        } catch (error) {
          console.log('Error!', error);
        }
      });
      document.getElementById('action-port').addEventListener('click', async () => {
        try {
          if (!my_serial.port.writable) {
            await my_serial.port.open({
              baudRate: 9600
            });
          }
          const encoder = new TextEncoder();
          const writer = await my_serial.port.writable.getWriter()
          let port_nr = document.getElementById('port-nr').value;
          let t = "AT+CH" + port_nr + "=" + (my_serial.is_open ? "0" : "1") + "";
          encoded = await encoder.encode(t);
          await writer.write(encoded);
          document.getElementById('status').setAttribute('class', !my_serial.is_open ? 'open' : 'closed');
          let pulse = document.getElementById('pulse').value;
          setTimeout(function () {
            my_serial.is_open = !my_serial.is_open;
            writer.releaseLock();
            my_serial.port.close().then(function () {
              if (my_serial.is_open) {
                document.getElementById('action-port').click();
              }
            });
          }, pulse);
        } catch (error) {
          console.log('Error!', error);
        }
      });
    }
  })
</script>
<style>
  #status>span {
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
  }
  #status.closed>span.hide-if-closed, 
  #status.open>span.hide-if-open {
    display: none;
  }
</style>
<div style="width:100%;align-items: center;">
  <div style="margin: auto;width:fit-content;">
    <h1>Test for DSD Tech SH-UR01A</h1>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2"><button id="select-port">Select USB-device</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label for="port-nr">Send to relay #</label></td>
          <td><input id="port-nr" value="1"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label for="pulse">Pulse duration (ms)</label></td>
          <td><input id="pulse" value="500"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2"><button id="action-port" disabled>Send open signal to device</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2">
            <h1 id="status" class="closed"><span>Status: </span><span class="hide-if-open">Closed</span><span class="hide-if-closed" style="color:green;">Open</span></h1>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```